# Visual Studio Code workbench (explorer) line height

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have researched like the whole internet about Visual Studio Code and didn't find any information about workbench (explorer with the project directories and files) entries line height.
**How can I change the line height in the workbench?**

I am asking, because this standard line height in Version: 1.65.2 is too huge for the project with many directories and files. I want to see relevant directories and files in the right structure without continuing scrolling, so I have to decrease this line height.

Comment: No solution? **:(**

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't adjust this. See this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/59873 and this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/519

Comment: @kanlukasz fortunately you can with the extension "Customize ui"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible out of the box, but possible with the extension "Customize UI".

Link to the extension: [Customize UI for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui)

*Last Update* info as of 2022-11-16:

```
More Info
Version 0.1.65  
Released on 6/6/2019, 7:47:09 AM    
Last updated    
9/25/2022, 3:51:30 AM
Publisher   iocave  
Unique Identifier   iocave.customize-ui
```

Feature list from the **Customize UI README**:

```
This experimental extension allows customizing VSCode user interface beyond what's
normally possible, such as:

Changing interface fonts
Inline titlebar on macOS
Activity bar below sidebar
Custom stylesheet rules conveniently specified in settings.json
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the overall goal is impossible, even considering plugins like Customize UI and [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) because **VSCode loads precisely the number of line items it calculates will fit on your screen**.

It is, however, technically possible to change the line height.

I wrote JavaScript and loaded with the Custom CSS and JS Loader extension to shrink the items from 22px to 18px to match my editor spacing, and I was left with the same number of explorer entries on my screen and a bunch of whitespace at the bottom.

For reference, here is that JavaScript:

```js
function modifyTopProperty(element) {
  let id = element.id;
  let index = parseInt(id.split('_').pop());
  let expectedTopValue = index * 18;

  let style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  let topValue = parseInt(style.top.replace('px', ''));

  // Only change the top value if it's not already at the expected value
  if (topValue !== expectedTopValue) {
    element.style.top = `${expectedTopValue}px`;
    element.style.height = `18px`;
    element.style.lineHeight = `18px`;
  }
}

let observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList' && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0) {
      mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
        if (node.matches && node.matches('.explorer-folders-view .monaco-list .monaco-list-row')) {
          modifyTopProperty(node);
        }
      });
    }
    if (mutation.type === 'attributes' && mutation.attributeName === 'style') {
      if (mutation.target.matches('.explorer-folders-view .monaco-list .monaco-list-row')) {
        modifyTopProperty(mutation.target);
      }
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['style'] });
```

Again, you will sadly get exactly the same number of elements on your list, but they will be smaller.  Perhaps [voting for this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/519) will increase the odds that this feature gets implemented.